# String containing double spaces retrieved from TypeORM mySQL is not plain text

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

When I retrieve an object from typeORM (mysql), if the string field value of the object contains a double space, it will not be returned as two plain spaces, but a symbol and a space. Hence, when I use the retrieved value for javascript property accessors, the output becomes undefined. The use case I have also requires symbols (utf-8). What is the error here, and how can I retrieve values with two spaces correctly?

```
const field_name_obj = {
  field_name : "some  name" // two normal spaces, no symbols.
}

const obj = {
  "some  name" : "value"
}

// typeORM.save(field_name_obj);
const get = typeORM.find(field_name_obj)

console.log(get.field_name) // "some  name"
console.log(obj[get.field_name])   // undefined
console.log(obj[field_name_obj.field_name]) // "value"
console.log(obj["some  name"]) // "value"
```

In this above example, if `"some  name"` was instead `"some name"`, `obj[get.field_name]` will return `"value"` as expected.

Table details:

```
Engine: InnoDB
Table collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Nothing in MySQL, whether utf8mb4 or otherwise, will change two spaces into one.  So, I point the finger at typeorm.

Comment: Ideally and best practice , Object property should contains a correct naming convention. Double white space is not a good naming convention and will break the statement while trying to access it.

Comment: Why does it break the statement while trying to access it?

Answer (score 2):

I also believe it's a TypeORM problem, as Rick James said.

Open a bug report [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues) and for now, you can mitigate the issue like this:

```
get = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(get).replaceAll('<symbol>','<space>'))
```

In the end, Please don't use spaces in object keys :)

Comment: I'll post a bug report. I cannot do replaceAll because the field names are supposed to allow symbols.

Comment: Then you need to iterate on `Object.keys(get)` and create another object with the correct keys I'm afraid.